# number field to limited digits without comma in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, validation

On my SharePoint online site I have a custom list with a Number field.I want to apply validation on this field so that the Number should not be less than or greater than 5 digits and it should be without commas and any wild characters.

Comment: You can use "PreSaveAction", an OOTB method to add validations before submitting the data.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/86fe14fc-f353-4521-bf88-fd7fcabaa768/using-presaveaction-in-newformaspx-in-sharepoint-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use input mask on that number field.

Below is the script:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script language="javascript" src="http://jquery-joshbush.googlecode.com/files/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
   $("input[title='Phone']").mask("(999) 999-9999? Ext.99999");
});
</script>
```

For your requirement, you can replace with below line:

```
$("input[title='NumberFieldName']").mask("99999");
```

Here is similar thread: [Column validation for US phone number format](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149106/column-validation-for-us-phone-number-format)

Reference: [Input mask on textbox](http://pawansatope.blogspot.in/2012/02/input-mask-on-textbox-in-sharepoint.html)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Naveen's answer, for making the user only enter 5 digits you can enter this formula in column validation: `=AND(Column>10000,Column<99999)`. You can then enter a custom message for that. Replace `Column` with your column name. As for the 2nd part of your question, since it's a number field it won't let you enter commas or wildcard entries.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put any validations formula just define the lowest i.e 10000 and highest 99999 number.
It will automatically restrict the special character in the field.

Done!!

Comment: I want to limit user to type only five digits for a better usability experience.

Comment: You wish to add only five digits in the field and without prompting status message as in case input is greater than 5 digit it should be trimmed to 5 right?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i needed. Is there any solution without programming? I am not very good in programming.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "List Settings". Click on your Number field. Under "Additional Column Settings" specify the minimum and maximum values as 10000 and 99999 respectively.

[image]

With respect to comma, SharePoint puts a comma where appropriate. So a number `43000` would be displayed as `43,000`. As for wildcard characters as it is a Number field it won't allow them to be save to List.

Comment: I want to limit user to type only five digits for a better usability experience. The user should be able to type only 5 digits at first place instead of having this weird  message while saving the item   (The value of this field must be between 10,000.00000 and 99,999.00000.)

Comment: @Jenny: For "user should be able to type only 5 digits", you will have to look into JSLink. [In SharePoint Online, in SharePoint Admin Center you need to enable "Custom Script" options to "Allow" for JSLink to be activated](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/135077/20540). Or you can do custom development using Visual Studio. Regarding the error message `The value of this field must be between 10,000.00000 and 99,999.00000.`, you can trim those extra decimals by setting the "Number of decimal places" to '0' as shown in my answer's screenshot.

Comment: @Jenny: Also, even if you set the maxlength for Number field to 5 (either using JSLink/Visual Studio), there's nothing to stop user's from entering values less than 5 characters in the field. So they would still receive the error `The value of this field must be between 10,000.00000 and 99,999.00000.` :)