# Column validation - can the column name contain special characters?

Tags: calculated-column, column-validation

I have a column called `Machine #`.  It is a Single line of text.  I would like it to be in this format:

- Mxxxxx - all the 'x digits' are numerical.
- The first item should be called `M00001`.
- I would like each item to contain 6 characters.

I've tried using `=LEN(Machine #)=6`, but I get an error message:

[image]

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  Could it be that the column name is causing the problem, since it contains a `#` ?  I created a test column without any special symbols and this enforced the 6 character column validation.

However, in [another question the $ symbol is used](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165968/column-validation-failed) in the column name and the column validation seems to accept the `$` symbol!

[image: Column validation pic]

Comment: Create the column with only name "Machine" and change the display name to "Machine #" then after. validation will work after changing the display name too.

Comment: remove your repeated question

Comment: I think you need to wrap a column name with a space with `[]`, so `=LEN([Machine #])=6`.