# Sharepoint Conditional Formatting or Add Flag?

Tags: formatting, conditional, file-icons

OK, so I'm trying to basically add an indicator of any kind in one field based on another field having data entered v no data entered. Ideally would like to display a red flag, or some kind of icon, but if its too complicated a simple change of color to the field (based on another) I'll make due with.

Comment: Is this a modern listview in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Client Side Rendering (CSR) to add an indicator based on values.

In the example [shown here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-97e27fa1), icon is shown based on Yes/No field. So you can achieve something similar to this.

Or you can change the color of the column value conditionally as shown in [another example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd).

You can go through many such examples of CSR [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a). You can implement the CSR in List Views as well as on List Forms.

Comment: I don't have a JSLink option under miscellaneous when I edit my list in a web part.

Comment: Is your SharePoint environment is on-premises or Online? Is it a custom List where you are trying to locate JSLink or is it any other List type?

Comment: Environment is online and the list is custom

Comment: If it is online, please refer [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135077/where-is-the-js-link-property).