# Is JSLink disabled in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jslink

Chris Cundy shared a link.
2 hrs
Is JsLink disabled in SharePoint Online?

I have been trying to get a CSR script that styles an annoucements list to work via JsLink however the style is not being rendered.

Has JsLink been deprecated by Microsoft in SharePoint Online??

The below link is what I'm trying to get working.

Any ideas??

https://www.c5insight.com/Resources/Blog/tabid/148/entryid/653/how-you-make-sharepoint-announcements-grab-attention-easily-using-csr.aspx

Comment: You can very well use JSLink/CSR in Sharepoint online classic model.

Comment: Is there any error message you are getting in console? Have you checked that your JS file of JSLink is loading properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint Admin Center you have to enable "Custom Script" options to "Allow". After this change, system will take around 24 hours to affect the site collection settings. Then that JS Link option will show-up.

Allow users to run custom script on personal sites
Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites
O365 Admin--> SharePoint --> Settings

If you want it to be run right away after these settings than use below mentioned PwoerShell commands:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://sitename-admin.sharepoint.com/ -credential admin@sitename.onmicrosoft.com

Set-SPOSite -Identity https://sitename.sharepoint.com/ -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $false

echo "Successfully completed."

pause
```

in addition, you can also Use SharePoint Designer for changing JSLink. Open your list in SharePoint Designer, then click to the view, and in the page editor you should be able to find the JSLink tag. Change its contents and that's it.

Reference:

[Where is the "JS Link" property?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135077/where-is-the-js-link-property)

Answer (score 1):

JSLink is not supported with modern lists and libraries; see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries

JSLink however should work with classic pages in SharePoint Online.

Comment: OK, so for example, is the list created as "Modern" at the point of adding a new 'announcements' app? If so, if browsing to Advanced Settings, if I change to Classic, does this make the list classic in its entirety or is it still classed as "Modern" under the hood??

Comment: I just performed the following in SharePoint Online: create a new custom list (which is a modern list by default), click "Switch to Classic View", add the list to a classic page, and the JS Link option is available.

Comment: Another test: add a modern custom list to a classic page: the JS Link option is available. So it looks like JS Link is not supported on modern pages, but classic pages allow JS Link still.

Comment: OK so this is the same for the announcements list, the JSLink bit is available but it doesnt seem to work.